# How to count the number of children accounts a Parent account has

Tags: roll-up-summary, count

I am having trouble figuring out a way to create a field within the Account Object that counts the number of children each parent account has. I can't use a simple roll-up summary field because the child parent accounts are not related through a master detail relationship. Is there a way to do this without doing an APEX Trigger? Or can someone help walk me through how to do the APEX Trigger?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). It's free and easy to use. Clicks not code!

Once you install the package, create the following `Lookup Rollup Summary` record:

- `Parent Object`: Account
- `Relationship Field`: ParentId
- `Child Object`: Account
- `Field to Aggregate`: Id
- `Aggregate Operation`: Count
- `Aggregate Result Field`: Child_Count__c *

`*` *You must create a custom field to store the result*

Once you have created the `Lookup Rollup Summary` record outlined above, click the <kbd>Manage Child Trigger</kbd> button. You will see a new page where you must click <kbd>Deploy</kbd>. Once deployment succeeds, hit <kbd>Cancel</kbd>. Then edit your record to check the `Active` checkbox.

Now your trigger is set up! It should work just fine, but you can also run a back-fill batch by hitting the <kbd>Calculate</kbd> button.

Comment: Yes, Andy Fawcett's stuff there is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SOQL query to retrieve the immediate Child count

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Account where ParentId='<Account Id>'
```